# error trying to find a saddle point in a matrix

Tags: java

I have written some code to find the position of a saddle point (an element within a matrix which is the maximum element of its corresponding row and simultaneously the minimum of its column) of a matrix. However, there is an error saying:

```
The local variable col may not have been initialized
at SaddlePoint.findSaddle(SaddlePoint.java:41)
at SaddlePoint.main(SaddlePoint.java:52)
```

I can't understand why it is saying so.  Any help would be very much appreciated.  Below I have given my code:

```
public class SaddlePoint {

    int arr[][]=new int[4][5];

    public SaddlePoint(int x[][])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
                arr[i][j]=x[i][j];
    }

    public void display(int x[][])
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++)
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+"\t");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public void findSaddle()
    {
        int row,col,flag;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {int max=arr[i][0];col=0;flag=0;
            for(int j=1;j<arr[i].length;j++)
                if(max<arr[i][j])
                {max=arr[i][j];
                    col=j;
                }
            for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++)
                if(arr[k][col]<max)
                {  flag=1;
                    break;
                }
            if(flag==0)
            {row=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
            System.out.println("The Position of the Saddle Point is at Row "+(row+1)+"& Column "+(col+1));
        else
            System.out.println("Not found.");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int array[][]   ={{12,8,37,15,16},{2,12,21,14,13},{15,47,23,20,19},{65,57,43,21,47}};
        SaddlePoint sadl=new SaddlePoint(array);
        sadl.display(array);
        sadl.findSaddle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't know if there will be any iterations of the `for` loop

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
```

There won't be if the array is of length zero.  So there is a possible case where `col=0;` never occurs and the variable is never initialized.

Initialize `col` before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing `col`, `row` and `flag` in your for block.

Your termination statement for the for block is:

`i<arr.length`

It may be false without for iterating once, then `col` will be not initialized.

Just initialize them when you declare them.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html):

> Each local variable and every blank final field must have a definitely
>   assigned value when any access of its value occurs.

So, if the compiler finds `col` uninitialized and *sees* a chance that it may remain uninitialized at runtime and also finds it being used later in the method, it flags this as an error.